# Why is getTermVectors always returning null?

Tags: java, lucene, morelikethis

So I'm trying to do some term vector analysis on an index, but when I run getTermVectors I always get null.  My index is created with the following attributes.

```
    type.setIndexed(true);
    type.setTokenized(true);
    type.setStored(true);
    type.setStoreTermVectors(true);
    type.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true);
    type.freeze();
```

Later on, when I want to get the vectors, I run the following code

```
Map<String, Int> termFreqMap = new HashMap<>();
for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
  final Fields vectors = ir.getTermVectors(docNum);
  ....
```

And vectors ends up being null for the whole loop.  Did I make a stupid mistake somewhere?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You might be indexing TextField. TextField is a convenience class for users who need indexed fields without term vectors. If you need terms vectors, just use a Field. It takes a few more lines of code since you need to create an instance of FieldType first, set storeTermVectors and tokenizer to true and then use this FieldType instance in Field constructor.